# Using LSO (Local Shared Objects) within iOS Development and Calling File Back Up

Tags: iphone, ios, object, local, shared

I am developing a app for iOS using Flash, and I've created a LSO using the following code:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("name");
so.data.user = enternamehere.text;
var result:String = so.flush();
```

I'm using a input text field so that users can enter their name. The instance name is "enternamehere".

I'd like to be able to call the information stored from the input text to appear on a different scene within the file.

So, a user enters their name on scene 3, and it appears on Scene 4 and the name is stored locally.

Any way of doing this?

Thanks